# Accessing a new table created after a join

Tags: sql-server, join, temp-tables

I have joined select columns from 3 tables into a new table using the following:

```
    SELECT A.ExternalID, A.UserDefinedXml.value('(Skin_Sheet/@Label)[1]', 'varchar(3)') AS SS, A.ServiceSiteUid, A.LastModifiedDate, A.PersonUid,
       B.FirstName, B.LastName, B.PersonUid,
       C.Name

  FROM Patient A
  INNER JOIN Person B ON B.PersonUid = A.PersonUid
  INNER JOIN ListServiceSite C ON C.ServiceSiteUid = A.ServiceSiteUid
  WHERE SS IS NOT NULL
  ORDER By LastModifiedDate;
```

This all works but I'm not sure how to reference the column  `SS` created from data extracted from the XML so I can only select the observations in which the value is "Yes" or "No". In R I would have created a new object but I'm not sure how SQL stores this new table if I don't specify what the table name is.

Side note, I did try to insert this into a new table but SQL wasn't letting me because, for some reason, the join resulted in `PersonUid` being duplicated. 
[image]

Thank you in advance, I'm very, very new to SQL and trying to learn on the fly.

Comment: That's just a query. You're not storing the data anywhere. You can `SELECT ... INTO ...` to create a table from the data, then reference that table. You could also use a temp table if you don't need to keep the data after you're finished working with it, or you could use a subquery or CTE if you only need the values for a single query.

Comment: Please read re [mcve]. Also please use text, not images/links, for text, including tables & ERDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually WHERE comes before SELECT, so you need to push the query into a derived table subquery or Common Table Expression (CTE) to reference `SS` in a WHERE clause.  EG

```
with q as
(
    SELECT A.ExternalID, A.UserDefinedXml.value('(Skin_Sheet/@Label)[1]', 'varchar(3)') AS SS, A.ServiceSiteUid, A.LastModifiedDate, A.PersonUid,
       B.FirstName, B.LastName, B.PersonUid,
       C.Name

  FROM Patient A
  INNER JOIN Person B ON B.PersonUid = A.PersonUid
  INNER JOIN ListServiceSite C ON C.ServiceSiteUid = A.ServiceSiteUid
)
SELECT *
FROM q
WHERE SS IS NOT NULL
ORDER By LastModifiedDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will put your results into a temp table, and avoids the problem of having two columns with the same name:

```
SELECT
    A.ExternalID
    ,SS = A.UserDefinedXml.value('(Skin_Sheet/@Label)[1]', 'varchar(3)')
    ,A.ServiceSiteUid
    ,A.LastModifiedDate
    ,PersonUid_A = A.PersonUid
    ,B.FirstName
    ,B.LastName
    ,PersonUid_B = B.PersonUid
    ,C.Name
INTO #TempResults
FROM Patient A
INNER JOIN Person B ON B.PersonUid = A.PersonUid
INNER JOIN ListServiceSite C ON C.ServiceSiteUid = A.ServiceSiteUid
WHERE SS IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY LastModifiedDate;
```